# Need to find the closest nearby prime number on python in basic terms

Tags: python, primes

I am a beginner at python, and I need to ask the user to enter a number n, and output the prime number closest to n.

If there are two primes equally close to n output the smaller of the two.

for example:
enter n: 17
The prime closest to 17 is 17
enter n: 6
The prime closest to 6 is 5

I can not use complex codes, so please help is the most basic way possible!!

*To give more detail, I have not tried anything, since I don't even know where to begin! I was told to write a code that checks if a number, like K, is prime or not, the put that code into a loop which starts with K, and keeps increasing until it find s a prime. Then do the same but downwards. Hope that helps

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?  You'll get better feedback if you show us what you've attempted.

Comment: You will need a function to test whether a given number N is prime or not. And you need to write a loop that checks N-1, then N+1, then N-2, then N+2 etc. You need to be careful when N-x becomes too small.

Comment: @JohanC what would that code look like for a python user?

Comment: Simplest test if K is prime: a loop L from 2 till K-1 and test whether K mod L == 0. Use % for mod. If K % L == 0 for some L, then K is not a prime.

Comment: Maybe you find some inspiration in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680930/closest-prime-number-in-python)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closest Prime Number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680930/closest-prime-number-in-python)

Comment: @rossum, I don't like that example as it arbitrary looks 100 numbers beyond `n` when we need to look closer to `n` numbers beyond `n`.

Comment: Then use Bertrand's Postulate.  You are guaranteed to find a prime between n/2 and n, and also between n and 2n.  Use n/2 and 2n as your lower and upper limits for the search.

Answer (score 0):

A sieve seems like the right approach, unlike the algorithm told to the OP.  If we sieve up to `n` and `n` is prime, we're done.  If not, we only need to find the first prime after `n` and then we know the answer.  Since `2` is always a worst case answer, we don't need to sieve beyond 2 * n.  And, as we find increasing primes less than `n`, we can decrease the size of our sieve, reducing the amount of striking we need to do.  Here's my unoptimized, example solution to this problem:

```
def closest_prime(n):
    if n <= 1:  # handle 0 & 1 as special cases
        return 2

    sieve_limit = 2 * n

    sieve = [False, False] + [True] * (sieve_limit - 2)

    prime_candidate = number = 2

    while number < sieve_limit:
        if sieve[number]:
            if number == n:
                return n  # n is prime

            if number > n:
                if (number - n) < (n - prime_candidate):
                    return number

                return prime_candidate

            prime_candidate = number

            sieve_limit = 2 * n - prime_candidate  # reduce sieve size

            for index in range(number * number, sieve_limit, number):
                sieve[index] = False

        number += 1

    return prime_candidate  # ran off end of sieve

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(20831428, closest_prime(20831428))
    print(20831429, closest_prime(20831429))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
20831428 20831323
20831429 20831533
>
```

I chose the above test case as there is a healthy gap of 209 between primes 20831323 and 20831533.  The code cited in the comments doesn't handle the second test correctly as it uses a hardcoded sieve upper limit.  As I noted above this code isn't optimized, for example:

- We can be smarter about even numbers to reduce testing and striking.
- We can adjust the sieve limit by one or so since we'll take the lower prime in the case of a tie.
- If `n - 1` is a prime, we can simply return that if `n` isn't a prime, rather than even looking for the first prime above `n`.